# Calculations involving kilowatt and kilowatt hour

Tags: energy, electricity, power

:)

I am very confused with the calculation involving kWh and kW. I have tried searching my question on Google but couldn't find anything.

Say, we have a device with a power rating of 1 kW.

This means that, when the device is turned on, for every second, 1000 joules of energy is being consumed right?

And if we want to calculate how much energy has been consumed by this device in one hour, we simply multiply the value of kW by 1.

So, my question is: since watt is equivalent to joule per second, **why don't we multiply 1 kW by 60 seconds, then by 60 minutes again?** How is it that we simply multiply the value of kW according to how many hours the device has been turned on for?

I hope what I am saying makes sense to you. :0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the energy consumed in Joules, you do need to take the power and multiply by $60 \times 60 = 3600$ seconds. However, if you want the energy consumed in kWh you just need to multiply the power by the time in hours. This means that

$$kWh = 1000W \cdot 1h = 1000 \frac{J}{s} \cdot 3600 s = 3.6\cdot 10^6 J $$

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply 1 kW by 3600 you are indeed finding total joules consumed in an hour.

That's not quite the same as a kilowatt hour.  The kilowatt hour is just a convenient way to measure energy usage.  It is fairly easy to determine power used in a circuit.  Generally most things we power with electricity, the purpose is to actually provide **power**, not energy.

These devices require a constant energy source to keep operating.  That's also how the power is generated, and how it is transmitted.

Essentially, most of our devices operate with respect to time, and therefore require a power draw.  It's a lot easier to measure and cost our electricity based on delivered power over a period of time, because those units fit in better with how the energy is delivered.  The units still end up as a form of energy, just one that is easier to convert back into power.  Instead of multiplying the power by the number of seconds and getting big numbers of joules, we multiply by hours, which is closer to the time scale we would expect to be drawing power on.

This is somewhat a supplemental answer to the other answer currently provided (showing the units), explaining more of the reasons why the units were chosen.